# How to specify interaction between crossed and nested factor levels?

Tags: mixed-model, interaction, random-effects-model, crossed-random-effects

We have estimated a mixed model with random factors where respondent (id) is nested within group and also crossed (fully) with stimulus. In lme4 syntax this is written as:

```r
y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + (1|group/id) + (1|stimulus)
```

Now a referee has suggested we add an interaction between stimulus and group to the model. I'm not sure how to specify this in lme4 syntax though, and would appreciate some help.

Comment: Could you give some more contextual info ? ... are stimulus fully crossed with group? Why do you model `stimulus` as a random effect?

Comment: Yes, stimulus is fully crossed with group - stimulus is a repeated measure with 7 levels, Group has 20 levels (categories). (I think) the referee is arguing that the response (y) to the stimulus will vary according to group level, hence the idea of an interaction between stimulus and group.